# Multiple calls to drawRect: in a content view of NSScrollView

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawrect, nsscrollview

I am designing a Quartz Composer-like interface, where the user can connect nodes with wires. The nodes are subclasses of `NSView` and the wires are drawn as `NSBezierPaths` on the canvas (also a subclass of NSView), in `-drawRect:`. The canvas is placed inside an `NSScrollView`.

I am facing an issue with the canvas view redraw. When the canvas view needs to be redrawn ( `-setNeedsDisplay:` or `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`), there are several calls to `-drawRect:` being made, instead of a single one, as one would expect. This slows down redrawing of the canvas significantly. I've done quite some optimization of the drawing of the bezier paths, but still this multiple redraw thing is killing my performance (as the paths still need to be blitted to screen the very least).

Here's a log of the `NSRect`s coming in `-drawRect:`, after a single `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` call :

```
Origin: 245.783616, 410.382009; Size: 740.000000, 813.000000
Origin: 768.000000, 410.000000; Size: 218.000000, 102.000000
Origin: 512.000000, 410.000000; Size: 256.000000, 102.000000
Origin: 256.000000, 410.000000; Size: 256.000000, 102.000000
Origin: 245.000000, 410.000000; Size: 11.000000, 102.000000
```

740 by 813 (first update) is the actual size of my viewport, but I have no idea where the rest of the updates are coming from, nor can I make sense out of the sizes and locations (in fact, some of the rectangles are overlapping).

I have since checked and double checked my code, and there are no redundant calls to any drawing functions, just a single call to `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`.

Here are my questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. I'd like to change this behaviour, to only have one update per call. How can I achieve this?
3. Or, the very least, is there a way to know when a "group" of these updates will begin (so as to more efficiently plan drawing)?
4. Any alternative strategies/suggestions to deal with this would be more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably due to [responsive scrolling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013207-SW10). Sadly, the 10.9 AppKit release notes which explain are not online (the current notes are for 10.10 and the older notes haven't had 10.9 added to them). In general, have you tried the optimization strategies in the [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I've done pretty much everything there is to do according to the guide you linked. But this is not about the drawing time itself (which is acceptable according to my standards), but rather about the inexplicable update habits of NSView. I took a look at what I could find about responsive scrolling, but it seems this might not be the root cause, because i. responsive scrolling only kicks in if the app can maintain 60fps (which is clearly not so in my case), and, ii. it happens in a background thread (also not the case, since all drawing happens in the main thread).